# Parse server issue with greaterThan and lessThan on queries using date fields

Tags: parse-platform

Queries with greater and less than are not returning any data when I am running parse on my local machine. Is there any workaround or am I missing something

**Environment Setup**

Running on local machine. I am using parse-server@2.2.6, node @v4.4.2, mongo 3.2.4.
I have my mongo db setup in ec2.

**Steps to reproduce**

I ran the test on both parse.com cloud code and my local server.
This is the code that I was running

```
Parse.Cloud.define("lessthangreatthan", function (request, response){
    var userActivityQuery = new Parse.Query("Activity");
    var updatedAt = request.params.updatedAt;
    var activityQuery = new Parse.Query("Activity");
    activityQuery.greaterThan("updatedAt", updatedAt);
    activityQuery.descending("updatedAt").limit(4);
    console.log(updatedAt);
    console.log(activityQuery);
    return activityQuery.find().then(function (activities) {
        response.success(activities);
    },function(err){
        response.error(err.message);
    });
});
```

When I run it on parse.com I get my results, but while running on local parse server it returns an empty.

This is my console.log for `activityQuery` when I run it on parse.com:

```
{"where":{"updatedAt":{"$gt":"2016-04-11T10:35:58.411Z"}},"limit":4,"order":"-updatedAt"}
```

This is my console.log for `activityQuery` when run on local parse server:

```
ParseQuery { className: 'Activity',_where: { updatedAt: { '$gt': '2016-04-11T10:35:58.411Z' } },_include: [],_limit: 4,_skip: 0,_extraOptions: {}, _order: [ '-updatedAt' ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out there are some differences in the parse-server and parse.com backend code. So parse.com somehow converts the updatedAt fields to Date type automatically but when we are running parse-server we need to convert them from our cloud code.